# Spring security- Sesiones?

Tags: java, spring

Tengo un proyecto creado con Spring Security y Spring MVC, y tengo una url de la siguiente forma:

```
universidad/acceso/infoNotas?idEstudiante=20
```

Resulta que al definir el acceso a la URL, está definida para el rol de docente de la siguiente forma:

```
.antMatchers("/acceso/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_DOCENTE')")
```

pero cada docente tiene un listado de cursos a los cuales puede acceder y solo debería ver las notas de los estudiantes para los cursos que el dicte; si copio la URL desde el áea de trabajo de cualquier profesor así dicho profesor no este vinculado con el curso al cual pertenezca el estudiante cuyo `idEstudiante` se referencia en la URL, puede ver sus notas, tengo la duda de como resolver ese problema de seguridad y me pregunto si tiene que ver con el manejo de sesiones y si alguien tiene una pista de como debería proceder. Muchas gracias

Comment: Se me ocurre que utilices programación orientada a aspectos para que puedas realizar la comprobación correspondiente (si el docente tiene dentro de sus cursos al estudiante con el id que viene en la URL de la petición) y si falla esta, retornas un código 403.

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que, como tienes Spring Security, has tenido que

1. Implementar `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`.
2. Implementar, por tanto, `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`

entonces tienes un bean que tiene la información que tú quieras del usuario con una sesión abierta.

A partir de aquí tienes dos opciones sencillas (posiblemente haya más, pero son las que he usado en algún momento y son sencillas):

**Opción A**: Hacer que todos tus controladores extiendan de una clase padre que tenga un método para obtener el usuario:

```
@Controller
public abstract class BaseController {
    protected MiUser getLoggedUser() {
        return (MiUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

De este modo en cualquier controlador podrás obtener el usuario y filtrar tus búsquedas.

**Opción B**: Añadir en cada método de los controladores el parámetro a inyectar por Spring:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Alumnos>> getAlumnos(@AuthenticationPrincipal MiUser principal) {
    ...
}
```

De este modo puedes hacer que un docente sólo vea los alumnos que le correspondan, o que sólo pueda ver los detalles de un alumno si está asociado a dicho docente de algún modo.